# Should viewDidUnload call super viewDidUnload or dealloc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

The template seems to create `[super viewDidUnload]` but code samples show:

```
[super dealloc]
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: What kind of messed up code sample calls `-dealloc` in `-viewDidUnload`?  Do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should only invoke the superclass' implementation of `-viewDidUnload`

**Never invoke `[super dealloc]` directly, except in your own `-dealloc` method**

```
- (void) viewDidUnload {
    ...
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

And

```
- (void) dealloc {
    //clean up here
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: A notable exception to this is that calling [super dealloc] as the last call of an object's own -dealloc is not only good practice, it'd be a memory leak not to do so ;)

Comment: @phooze OMG I cannot believe I didn't mention that! Thanks!

Comment: that's why I love this site - we've all got each other's backs :)

Comment: That's weird, because Apple's documentation says: "In an implementation of dealloc, do not invoke the superclass’s implementation."

Comment: @exalted That's because of Automatic Reference Counting. This answer came before it.